# GNU Make: expand pattern before passing to Shell

Tags: regex, awk, makefile, gnu-make

I want to use an awk script to figure out the which modules have to be compiled before I can compile a FORTRAN source file. My project is structured in a way that I can obtain the filenames that provide the modules by running

```
awk '$1=/use/{print gensub(",","","g", $2) ".o"}' file.f90
```

on the file I want to compile.

However, my make command

```
%.o: $(shell awk '$$1=/use/{print gensub(",","","g", $$2) ".o"}' /path/to/%.f90)
```

fails with

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `/path/to/%.f90' for reading: No such file or directory
```

So %.f90 does not get expanded. Why is that the case and how can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables and functions in targets and prerequisites are expanded when the makefile is parsed, not when make is running the makefile.  But, pattern rules are only expanded when make is running the makefile, trying to build a target that matches the pattern.  So at the time these variables and functions are expanded, you only have the literal pattern string not its expansion into a real filename.

See [How make reads a makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html) in the docs.

There are a number of ways to do this.  One option is using [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html).  However note you'll have to double-escape the `$` you are escaping!!

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.o: $$(shell awk '$$$$1=/use/{print gensub(",","","g", $$$$2) ".o"}' /path/to/$$*.f90)
```

**ETA**

You could alternatively not use `.SECONDEXPANSION` at all and instead use `eval` like this:

```
%.o:
        ...

SRCS := $(wildcard *.f90)
OBJS := $(SRCS:%.f90=%.o)

$(foreach O,$(OBJS),\
    $(eval $O: $(shell awk '$$1=/use/{print gensub(",","","g", $$2) ".o"}' $(O:%.o=%.f90))))
```

Since you didn't give an actual example I just made up `SRCS` and `OBJS` variables.  Maybe you have similar variables already.

Comment: You changed my %.f90 to \*.f90 so it will match all files that end in '.f90'. That is not what I want. When I build test.o it should run this command on test.f90 and not on all files that end in .f90. However, simply changing $$*.f90 to $$%.f90 does not work.

Comment: Did you actually try what I wrote to see if it worked?  You're not correct in your statement.  I wrote `$$*.f90` which will reduce to `$*.f90` and `$*` is the automatic variable that expands to the stem of the rule: that is the value that `%` takes on.

Comment: I'm really sorry! I did test it, but there was another issue in my (more complicated) Makefile. Now I think I figured most things out. Thanks! 

Just that I got it right: under normal circumstances, % and $* is the same?

Comment: `$*` is an automatic variable: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html  As you can see there, though, automatic variables are only valid within recipes normally.  So, you use `%` in the target and prerequisites and `$*` in the recipe.  Secondary expansion allows (some) automatic variables to be visible when expanding the prerequisites as well.

Comment: This only works on gnu make version 3.82 or higher. On mac usually 3.81 seems to be installed. There I get $$*.f90 expands to basename.f90.f90 so "f90" is added twice. How can this be changed so that it also works on make 3.81?

Comment: The SECONDEXPANSION feature was added in GNU make 3.81 so it does exist there.  If it doesn't work in this situation maybe there was a bug in that first release that was fixed in a subsequent release: GNU make 3.81 is over 16 years old now.  I recommend you get a newer version of GNU make and don't rely on the ancient software versions that MacOS ships.

Comment: I don't have a mac, but users that want to use my software do complain that it does not compile on mac. It would be very nice if it could be fixed on my side so that it will work with the version installed on mac. By compiling 3.81 on Linux I can confirm that this issue also does not only effect mac but all systems running make 3.81

Comment: Just out of interest, you said that there are several ways to achieve the desired behavior, could you give a hint how theses other ways look like?

Comment: Ok, I think [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html) is what I was looking for

Comment: Yes or you can use generated include files instead, that works too.